# Order of an algebraic number

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, polynomials

Consider some arbitrary polynomial with integer coefficients,

$$a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0 = 0$$

We'll assume that \$a_n \ne 0\$ and \$a_0 \ne 0\$. The solutions to this polynomial are [algebraic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number). For example, take the polynomial $$x^4 - 10x^2 + 1 = 0$$

We have that \$x = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3\$ is a solution to this polynomial, and so \$\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3\$ must be an algebraic number. However, most real numbers, such as \$\pi\$ or \$e\$ are not algebraic.

Given any algebraic number \$x\$, it is possible to construct a polynomial \$p\$ such that \$p(x) = 0\$. However, this is not unique. For example, $$x^6 - 99x^2 + 10 = 0$$ also has a root \$x = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3\$. We define the *minimal polynomial* of an algebraic number \$x\$ to the be polynomial \$p\$ such that \$p(x) = 0\$ and the order of \$p\$ is minimal. With our example \$x = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3\$, there exists no such quadratic or cubic polynomial with \$x\$ as a root, as \$x^4 - 10x^2 + 1\$ is the minimal polynomial of \$x = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3\$. If the order of \$p\$ is \$n\$, we say that \$x\$ is an "algebraic number of order \$n\$". For example, \$\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3\$ is of order \$4\$.

---

For the purposes of this challenge, we'll only consider **real** algebraic numbers termed "[closed form algebraic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Closed-form_number)". These are algebraic numbers that can be expressed as some combination of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and \$n\$th order radicals (for integer \$n\$).

For example, this includes \$\varphi = \frac {1 + \sqrt 5} 2\$, and \$7\sqrt[3] 2 - \sqrt[10] 3\$, but not e.g. [roots of \$x^5 - x - 1 = 0\$](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvJDo4P6csNboizlRBV6ECiA0VbG0VDGJj//8HAA), or \$\sqrt[\sqrt 2] 3\$ (\$n\$th roots are only allowed with integer \$n\$).

You are to take a real algebraic number as input, with the guarantee that it can be constructed with our 5 operations, and output the order of the input. The order will always be a positive integer.

You may take input in any form that exactly represents any closed form algebraic numbers. This could be as an exact symbolic number (if your language has these), a string unambiguously representing the composition of the 5 operations (e.g. `7*root(2,3)-root(3,10)`, `7*(2r3)-(3r10)` or even `sub(times(7, root(2, 3)), root(3, 10))`), and so on. **You may not input as floating point values**. Note that the format you choose should be unambiguous, so is likely to use e.g. parentheses for grouping/precedence. For example, `7*2r3-3r10` does not meet this requirement, as it can be interpreted in a number of ways, depending on the precedence of each command.

In short, you may choose any input format - not limited to strings - so long as that input format can represent any closed form algebraic number exactly and unambiguously. Additionally, be mindful of [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14110/66833) standard loophole about encoding extra information into the input format - this is fairly loose, but try not to use formats that contain more information than just the 5 standard operations.

If your answer uses a builtin that takes an algebraic number as input and returns either the order of the number, or the minimal polynomial, please edit it into [this list of trivial answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240112/66833).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

---

### Test cases

I'm expressing the inputs here using Mathematica's `Surd[n, k]` function to represent \$\sqrt[k] n\$, along with `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` to represent \$+\$, \$-\$, \$\times\$ and \$\div\$ respectively.

```
input -> output
5/6 -> 1
Surd[4, 2] -> 1
Surd[2, 2] * Surd[2, 2] -> 1
(Surd[5, 2] + 1)*(Surd[5, 2] - 1) -> 1
(Surd[5, 2] + 1)/2 -> 2
(Surd[5, 2] + 1)*(Surd[5, 2] + 1) -> 2
Surd[2, 2] + Surd[3, 2] -> 4
Surd[(Surd[5, 2] + 1)/2, 2] -> 4
Surd[5, 5] - 2 -> 5
Surd[5, 5] + Surd[3, 7] - 2*Surd[2, 2] -> 70
```

The polynomials for these cases are given by [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvJNo3My8zNzEnID@nMi8/NzMxJ1pZR6EiNlZNQd9BoZpLAQhM9c10wIzg0qKUaBMdBaNYJL4RiK@ghcSBSGqABUzBstoKhppayAK6QAHsyvSNiNCuDdeO5ARtCMcYzX1YLEBVAJQyBbnICEMMYaI5WIEWwjau2v//AQ)

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24163/66833)

Comment: To my understanding, the \$n\$th order radicals rule only require \$n\$ be integer. But not the expression in it. So \$ \sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}} \$ is a valid expression for input. If so, I would suggest add any of them.

Comment: Some testcases: `Surt[4, 2] -> 1`, `Surd[2, 2] * Surd[2, 2] -> 1`.

Comment: Some more testcases: `(Surd[5, 2] + 1) (Surd[5, 2] - 1) -> 1`, `(Surd[5, 2] + 1) (Surd[5, 2] + 1) -> 2` (thanks to @tsh ). My answer using resultants cannot tell the difference between these two.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all subexpressions are real? There might be cases where the whole expression is a real algebraic number, but some part of it is not real.

Comment: @alephalpha For simplicity's sake, I'll say that yes, all subexpressions will be real, and you don't have to worry about complex arithmetic

Answer (score 3):

## Trivial builtin answers

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 33 bytes

```
#~MinimalPolynomial~x~Exponent~x&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/Bfuc43My8zNzEnID@nMi8/NzMxp66izrWiID8vNa@krkLtf0BRZl5JdFq0qb5ZbCwXjBdcWpQSbaqjYBSrb6SgrWCob4QuaQSSBEqBOcYgDhbtprEKugpG2CUQWs3BqrQQxsbG/gcA)

Unsurprisingly, `MinimalPolynomial` returns the minimal polynomial of its input, and `Exponent` gets the highest exponent in this polynomial. We use a bit of infix notation (`a~f~b` is `f[a,b]`) to save a couple of bytes, and so this translates as

```
#~MinimalPolynomial~x~Exponent~x&
Exponent[#~MinimalPolynomial~x,x]&
Exponent[MinimalPolynomial[#,x],x]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 175 bytes

```
Cases[FactorList@g@#,{y_,_}/;Simplify[y/.x->#/.s->D]==0:>y~Exponent~x]&
g@n_=x-n
g[p_~s@o_~q_]:=Resultant[g@q,g@p/.x-><|Plus->z-x,Times->z/x,Divide->z*x,Surd->z^q|>@o,x]/.z->x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVBNS8NAEL33VywEepDdxEarUM2yYPXkoVhvyxpCm8SFfO9GNv3IX4/5MNqUIIK3eTNv3nszoSPf3dCRfONUHrCqB0e4gj45Gxlnz1xI4hMN7gsb2kfjbs3DJOBeQQtDVwhrhi4QXjLLulzgonxUSRy5kSwVm058EtmWQtHEp4ldChLbZWqzhfXiijyQTiSpT1Lok6RVuj@sgrzW2iEFX3noNqWh4JJ/8K1b1xcKrvNsW1dv6QGTGCpm6DuEVbXKeK2lAYSBRzXGwBQYBOwF7XYZnUNwwyAQtBFg9BoCs4WtDaN93@z7J3DIaxL@8Ocdf9ZyRkdo1gn0QX5RMP/n9GU0nJ0ddPV9UIf/nMsc9503Fw5no5wT/9vBQ5F5/m12rD4B)

Takes an expression as input, where:

- \$p+q\$ is represented by `s[Plus][p, q]`.
- \$p\ q\$ is represented by `s[Times][p, q]`.
- \$p/q\$ is represented by `s[Divide][p, q]`.
- \$\sqrt[n]p\$ is represented by `s[Surd][p, n]`.
- There is no special form for \$p-q\$, because \$p-q\$ is just \$p+(-1)\times q\$.

For example, \$\sqrt[5]5+\sqrt[7]3-2\sqrt[2]2\$ is represented by `s[Plus][s[Plus][s[Surd][5, 5], s[Surd][3, 7]], s[Times][-2, s[Surd][2, 2]]]`.

The idea is constructing a (usually not minimal) polynomial using [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant), factoring it, and choosing the correct factor. The last step requires checking whether a expression is equal to zero. I'm not sure if `Simplify` is powerful enough for all possible inputs, but at least it works for all the testcases.

Comment: Is `m[a[r[5,2],1],s[r[5,2],1]]` a correct encoding to \$\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1} \cdot \sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}\$?

Comment: @tsh That is \$\sqrt{(\sqrt{5}+1)(\sqrt{5}-1)}\$... Thanks for finding a bug.

Answer (score 1):

## Trivial builtin answers

### [Python](https://www.python.org) + [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), 78 bytes

```python
from sympy import*
x=symbols('x')
f=lambda y:degree(minimal_polynomial(y,x),x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZDBasMwDIbveQpBD7XalLKUbGPQ0-477AWGu9iNwbY8R9niZ-mll-1h-gZ9myUhK4MWdJD4P30gHX5C4pr88fjdsl49nl90JAdNciGBcYEiL7Ju2887so2Yd3PM9NZKt6skpKdK7aNSwhlvnLRvgWzy5Iy0IuUd9jVZTzN4ltYC1wp069_ZkIcvwzVURmsVlWf4lLZVTRai8Sy0eJUD1JvKHO4R8RI0H5FFiesClnCB7nIorqACe2TsNv-zSMSDtURYDVu3giWMwyaHh5FaTEKcLvr71y8)

Comment: This should be edited into the [Trivial builtins answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240112/66833)